# Unsupervised fine-tuning on custom documents after the supervised fine tuning on general question-answers dataset. Will it be useful for GPT-2 model?

Tags: pre-trained-model, gpt-2, large-language-model, semisupervised-learning, generative-pretrained-transformer

I know the formal way of training a GPT2 model on custom documents is to first do semi-supervised fine tuning on the text of the documents followed by supervised fine-tuning on question answers from the same documents.
But the sole purpose of supervised fine-tuning being to acquire style of answering question, is it possible to do supervised fine-tuning on a general dataset, and after that perform unsupervised fine-tuning on our custom text dataset from documents.
This way question answering style can also be acquired by the model along with the advantage of having no need of making a question-answer dataset for the custom documents.

Will it give the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

It is very difficult to say this methodology would 'work' reliably for use cases. One approach I have tried is taking a base model and [causally](https://huggingface.co/learn/nlp-course/chapter7/6) fine-tuning it on the documents at hand. Following this, you can take a publicly created Q&A dataset like [SQuAD](https://rajpurkar.github.io/SQuAD-explorer/) and further fine-tune in a prompt + expected response way. During this supervised stage, much research has shown that using Parameter Efficient methods for this task adaptation stage is more beneficial than training all weights (see [LoRa](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.09685.pdf)).

Finally, I will say this: for Question and Answering systems, I personally have found that using In-Context learning has been far more beneficial than fine-tuning and closed-book Q&A - even in the case that using Vector DBs and Embeddings is required to search for relevant chunks of context.